# Meaning of MeshCells for CantorMesh?

Tags: regions, mesh

Let

```
    cantor2 = CantorMesh[2]
```

As expected:

```
    RegionBounds[cantor2]
(* {{0., 1.}} *)
```

And as expected:

```
    Flatten@Rationalize@MeshCoordinates[cantor2]
(* {0, 1/9, 2/9, 1/3, 2/3, 7/9, 8/9, 1} *)
```

Then what is the meaning of the output below?

```
    MeshCells[cantor2, RegionDimension[cantor2]]
(* {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{3, 4}], Line[{5, 6}], Line[{7, 8}]} *)
```

I *expected* it to be a list of lines with endpoints the various rational numbers in the interval from 0 to 1.

Comment: You want `MeshPrimitives[]`: `MeshPrimitives[CantorMesh[2], 1] // Rationalize`. See the second bullet point under "Details" in the `MeshCells[]` doc page.

Comment: @J.M.: OK, that gives what I want. But what then does `MeshCells[CantorMesh[2], RegionDimension[CantorMesh[2]]]` mean?

Comment: The integers are indices into the `MeshCoordinates[]` similar to `GraphicsComplex[]`.